# Avoid memory leak on microtask debouncer

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I'm trying to fix a memory leak I have with this microtask based debouncer:

```
function microtaskDebounce(fn) {
    let scheduled = false;
    let i = 0;
    let elem = document.createElement('span');

    // MutationObserver provides a mechanism for scheduling microtasks, which
    // are scheduled *before* the next task. This gives us a way to debounce
    // a function but ensure it's called *before* the next paint.
    const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        fn();
        scheduled = false;
    });

    observer.observe(elem, { childList: true });

    return () => {
        if (!scheduled) {
            scheduled = true;
            elem.textContent = `${i}`;
            i = i + 1; // don't use compund (+=) because it doesn't get optimized in V8
        }
    };
}

// usage example
const fn = microtaskDebounce(someFunction.bind(this));
for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  fn();
}
```

This is the timeline with a `setTimeout` based debouncer:
[image]

This, instead, is the timeline with the microtask debouncer:
[image]

As you can see, with microtask debouncer, the DOM element I use to detect the repaints seems to leak and pollutes the memory.

How can I fix it?

For reference, this is the library where I am using this function:
https://github.com/FezVrasta/popper.js/blob/v1-dev/src/popper/index.js#L132

### Update

replacing `elem.textContent` with `elem.setAttribute('x-index', i)` and observing with `observer.observe(elem, { attributes: true });` fixes the leak.
I still don't understand why `innerText` causes a memory leak though!

I reproduced the problem in this CodePen:
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/pRomWL

Open it in `debug mode`, let the timeline record the page load, and you will see thousands of nodes in memory.

Comment: Please show us your whole code. The `microTaskDebounce` function is never called in your excerpt and never creates any nodes.

Comment: Can you explain how your debouncer is supposed to work? I don't get what "`when finished`" means in that comment.

Comment: I added an usage example @Bergi

Comment: The debounced function is still never called anywhere? Please show us the code that you used to generate those graphs.

Comment: Sorry, added a complete usage. It's just like any other debouncer function, the usage is the same.

Comment: Ignore the `else` branch, I added it as an attempt to fix the memory leak but obviously it's wrong.

Comment: How many times are you calling `microTaksDebounce`? I'd expect it to create a single node only.

Comment: I call it only in the constructor, one time.

Comment: Actually the dom element created is one, but somewhere there's a memory leak. Maybe the `textContent` creates a new in memory node?